# How do I use html form to "patch" database?

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, patch

I am trying to patch documents in my mongoDB database using javascript. I am aware that forms can only accept post/get as a method, which works, so I am looking for a work around so I am able to patch the document.

I have tried a hidden input with "_method" and "patch", but I was either doing something wrong, or it didn't work.

I have my database organized in a table and have an "edit" button which ideally would patch the document with new information by simply clicking a submit button.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, html5 only supports `GET` and `POST`, but there is a way to do that with [method-override](https://www.npmjs.com/package/method-override)